# Change Background Color For CPT Template

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, themes, css, custom-background

Please help. Anyone knows of the proper way how to change the background color for a custom post type template only? Using chrome's inspect, I saw that my theme uses the ID of "#main" for all the page's background color so if I try changing it, all pages got affected. Just looking for a way on how only the CPT template will get affected. If it helps, below is a snapshot of the theme.

[image: New attachment]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the body's classes :

```css
body.single-artist #main{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Collapse the `<div id="main">`. I hope that you have `<article>` tag which id and class attributes like below

```
<article id="post-212" class="post-212 post type-post status-publish format-video has-post-thumbnail hentry category-resources post_format-post-format-video active">
```

Inside the class attribute you can find the post type as **type-post**, so you can write css for `post.type-post`  if you have used `<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>` like this in your custom post type template and your custom post type name is article for example, then you have a class called **type-article** inside the class attribute of `<article>` tag.

Also you can add you own class by `<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('my-custom-post-type-name'); ?>>`

Comment: Thanks!! I was able to get the post type class and change its background color temporarily to #CCC (you can see that on the updated screenshot above). However, it still shows a left and right white background which is controlled by the div id "main". How can I make its background color changed only for my CPT Template?